# Always getting 'definition for rule 'no-useless-catch' was not found' in Eslint (v 6.0.0) when doing import React

Tags: reactjs, eslint, eslintrc

I have tried to google this but to no avail so far...

In a standard React project, every component typically begins with `import React from 'react'`. For me, with Eslint v6.0.0 configured to extend: `'standard', "eslint:recommended", "plugin:react/recommended"` I always get this warning in vscode:

`Definition for rule 'no-useless-catch' was not foundeslint(no-useless-catch)`

.. for the very first `import` in a javascript file.

[image: vscode screenshot]

Any ideas on why this is happening? I don't want to disable the rule because it does seem useful but how do I configure eslint to not complain about this in literally every file in the project?

Here is the complete eslintrc file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true
  },
  parser: 'babel-eslint',
  extends: [
    'standard',
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended"
  ],
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true
    },
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module'
  },
  plugins: [
    'react'
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
    "indent": ["warn", "tab", { "ignoreComments": true }],
    "no-tabs": 0,
    "padded-blocks": 0,
    "semi": ["warn", "never"],
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "spaced-comment": 0,
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": 0,
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "camelcase": 0,
    "prefer-const": "warn",
    "space-infix-ops": "warn",
    "no-case-declarations": 0,

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, figure it out ... I was using eslint 5.6 and the `no-useless-catch` rule was not introduced until 5.11 hence the error...

Comment: I updated my project packages and got this, had to update my global eslint to fix it.